# What should I do if I find a logo very similar to my design?

Tags: logo, copyright, plagiarism

I designed this "LUCENTICITY" logo 2 days ago. I swear it was my idea. I chose the design after many sketches.

[image: My design]

Today I was browsing the old featured logos on LogoPond and was shocked to come across this similar "NOS" logo. (It was [added July 14th, 2006](http://logopond.com/gallery/detail/72).)

[image: Existing design]

What should I do now? Change my design? My client has already finalized the attached "LUCENTICITY" logo!

Will people think I'm stealing?

Comment: I wouldnt really label it as logo stealing.  I would label it as "poor research", "poor branding" or "no originality"...  In no way am I trying to be rude but your logo is a "stock logo" and has been done numerious times plus has no meaning except what would appear as a broad usage of color.  If you do a search for polygon stock logo you will see several similar to yours.

Comment: well, you are exposing yourself to a legal problem. I'd recommend you to change it, choose another one. If you don't, legal issues may fond you.-

Comment: Just a guess.. but you created your design after seeing the NOS logo previously while browsing logopond.com... the idea stuck even if subconsciously.

Comment: NO @Scott, I made this logo without seeing the "NOS" logos. Its just my habit to browse good designing websites. I accidentally came across NOS's logo

Comment: *"Its just my habit to browse"* - That's my point. You subliminally picked up on it.

Comment: After this link is a montage / example of overused and generic logos [generic logo examples](http://www.gtgraphics.org/genericlogos.html)

Comment: I hate to break it to you, but i've seen so many similar hexagon logos (with the rainbow scheme) in the 13 years of printing I'm in.... Just using a hexagon is not the most original thing by itself. Do a google image search of "hexagon logo" and an infinite number of hexagon logos with similar rainbow color schemes pop up.

Answer (score 10):

Personal opinion:
I suppose you have not *technically* stolen it, but you should not use it. It is way too close. You have to tell your client what happened, and that it is in everyones interest to change it.

...and even if you used it, I would be very uncomfortable if my company had a logo that was so easily confused with another company.

Answer (score 3):

Don't worry. Did NOS invent the Hexagon? No. Did they invent the colours they use? No.

Answer (score 2):

Its' not technically stealing because you did not know that there was another company with a similar logo. However it could easily be perceived as stealing due to the similarity so I would say that to avoid legal troubles, you should tell your client the research error you have made and come up with a new logo :)

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion the logo is not really good, because it just seems quite generic, but if you are the only company on the specific market that uses a coloured hexagon it doesn't matter as much.

Considering that Lucenticity sells colourful kitchens, the logo actually reminds you of it, but without research on the name you wont know what Lucencity sells. (I thought it would be something light related.)

The fact that the logo looks like the NOS logo shouldn't be a problem, as you are using the colours without a fade and in a partly different configuration. If both companies were in the same market I would definitely  not try to use it.

Answer (score 1):

Does NOS and LUCENTICITY operate in the same fields or the same area?
If fields of operations/communications of both companies overlap each other; if in any way one can prove the other is creating a threat to its business, then you might have legal issues.

If business matter and operations zones are distinct, then the only thing that might be affected is brand image and/or notoriety, which rather extends to the marketing side of branding. Then i believe it's something you might want to discuss with your client.

Answer (score 1):

What are the reasons for the shapes / colors / fonts you used in the logo? Can you defend the process of your design and how you came up with the elements?

If your process validates the design, because it relates to the ethos of the business then it should be okay to use. If you choose the design because it looks pretty, then I would say move on to another design.